# requests.post returns isSuccess:false even though Postman returns true

Tags: python, rest, post, postman

I am trying to post some information into an API based on their recommended format. When I use Postman( tool to test APIs), I see that the response has the isSuccess flag set to true. However, when I write the same code in Python using the requests library, I get the isSuccess flag as false

As mentioned about, I verified the headers and the json data object, both are the same yet the results defer

```
import requests

data = {"AccountNumber":"100007777",
        "ActivityID":"78",
        "ActivityDT":"2019-08-07 12:00:00",
        "ActivityValue":"1"
        }

url = "http://<IP>/<API_PATH>"

headers = {
        "X-Tenant":"Default",
        "Content-Type":"application/json"
        }

response = requests.post(url,data=data, headers = headers)
print(response.content)
```

This code should successfully post the data and I should get a isSuccess:true in my response variable.

Can anyone help me figure out what might be wrong?[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you try to change;

```
response = requests.post(url,data=data, headers = headers)
```

to;

```
response = requests.post(url,json=data, headers = headers)
```

or;

```
response = requests.post(url,body=data, headers = headers)
```

Comment: That worked! I didn’t know you need to specify what type of data you are sending in even though it’s clearly a json. Thank you!